# Can't Update ObjectListView On Main Form From Class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, objectlistview

I am hoping someone can help me with an issue I have:

I have a main form with an ObjectListView control on it.  When I add objects to the control via code on the Main form, everything works fine, however....

I have a Class that does some processing.  This class kicks off a ThreadPool to process incoming information, and once complete, I am trying to update the ObjectListView stored on the Main Form.

The weird thing is I get absolutely no errors and the debugger steps through fine, it's just that nothing ever gets populated on the control via that Class.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

So this gives me nothing:

```
Dim _activityItem As New ActivityItem
frmMain.lsvActivity.AddObject(_activityItem)
```

Yet it works fine on frmMain

**Update**
I've turned off the ThreadPooling and it still doesn't update the ObjectListView control.

**Update 2**
Just to try and make things a little clearer, I'll explain how may app works (briefly):

- When my Main Form loads, I start a thread to listen for incoming
  messages
- Any population made to the ObjectListView is fine from the Main Form
- When a message is received, it is passed to a MessageHandling Class
  to decode
- Once decoded, it is passed into a Thread Pool for processing
- Once all processing is complete, a status is given to the user through the ObjectListView but still within the MessageHandling Class (using the code snippet explained above)
- The application then repeats the entire process for each incoming
  message or until exited

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
frmMain.Invoke(Sub() frmMain.lsvActivity.AddObject(_activityItem))
```

You shouldn't access the UI controls directly from any threads other than the UI thread.
[`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) executes the specified delegate on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  My problem actually consisted of two separate issues.  1. I had to create an instance of frmMain on the same Class as where I was trying to update the ListView and 2. I had to implement your Invoke method to prevent cross-thread calls.  The ThreadPooling was fine and I was able to turn that back on.  Thanks Ripple for your help...and like the name!  ;-)